# Can I pause EV training?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I want to stop EV training my Pokémon for awhile and train them normally so they level up faster. Does this affect my EV points (do all Pokémon give EV values?), or is there an item which stops the Pokémon from getting EV points?

Comment: Yes, all Pokémon yield EV values

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No**, there is no way at all to prevent your Pokemon from getting EV if they getting experience (so participating in the fight, and don't die). So you either fight hordes of Pokemon that give the right EV (for example, a stat you already maximised or one that you want to), or complete the EV training.

Answer (score 2):

Like Marciano said, you can't prevent Pokemon from getting EV's. BUT if you want to EV train them differently, use a Reset Bag found in Super Training to remove all their EV's.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Rare Candy to increase their levels **without** affecting their EVs.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @aytimothy - Actually, it kinda does answer the question :). Rare Candies are a valid way of levelling up whilst avoiding EV points.

Comment: @Robotnik Oops.. I forgot rare candies gives you free level-ups essentially. I just didn't see the question..